# Recursion in non static method

Tags: java, recursion, non-static

I couldn't find an answer to this on the forums, sorry if this has been answered and I missed it.

I am drawing a blank here on using recursion on a non static method.

Example:

```
  public static void farLeft(BTNode root){
     if(root !=null)  
       return farLeft(root.left);
  }
```

This is just some random code I put in here. Now if I wanted to do that exact same thing using a non-static method, how would I use recursion on a non-static method? My book doesn't do a good job at explaining it.

Comment: It's unlikely to make a difference whether a method is static or non static when it comes to recursion. Could you give an example of a method where you think it would?

Comment: Any method can recurse as long as it has a termination condition. If it is non-static you simply need to call it as a method of an instance of a class.

Comment: remove `static` ? which class are you in?

Comment: @BoristheSpider yes. ur right.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning a non-void object in a method that is returning void. Other than that, you can just use a non-static method like this:

```
public BTNode farLeft(BTNode root){
    if(root !=null)
        return farLeft(root.left);

    //Return root because root has no left child
    return root;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a non static method you will need to call it using the class instance.
The method should not be private.

If the method is implemented in the class `BTNode` it would look something like this:

```
public BTNode farLeft(BTNode root){
     if(root !=null)  
         return root.farLeft(root.left);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public BTNode farLeft(BTNode root)
{
    BTNode farLeftChild = null;
    if(root !=null)
    {
        farLeftChild = farLeft(root.left);          
    } 

    return farLeftChild == null? root : farLeftChild;
}
```

Hope this helps. Good luck and have fun programming!

Cheers,

Lofty